# How to realize number calculation automatically in PYQT5 tablewidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, sum, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I create a table in 4 rows and 2 columns. I want to add the three numbers in one column and show the summation in the last row automatically. Such as:

```
1  2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9
12 15 18
```

If there is no any number in the table, the last row should be all 0s or showing nothing.
I put the code of creating table here.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QTableWidget, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot


class App(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.left = 200
        self.top = 200
        self.width = 300
        self.height = 200
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.createTable()

    # Add box layout, add table to box layout and add box layout to widget
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

    # Show widget
        self.show()

    def createTable(self):
    # Create table
        self.tableWidget = QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(4)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I considered to use double click function in tablewidget but it's not what I'm looking for. So now I'm thinking about multi-thread. But I have no idea about it.

Does someone have any thoughts or suggestions? Thank you!

Comment: This is the same question that I answered 3 days ago. You should do a search before asking. Please read the following for a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @eyllanesc Thank you for your information. I have been searching the answer in Stackoverflow for a whole day! But I didn't find that question. Both questions are using different key words. I have searched on Google and didn't find an answer so I posted my question in here. Anyway, thanks for the information.